# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/before.txt' -> 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/after.txt'

Tags: python, import, rename

[image]

```
import os 

os.rename("C:\Users\user\Desktop\before.txt","C:\Users\user\Desktop\after.txt")
```

I want to Know why that message come.
I already search a lot of documents  and try change /->\ and attach r before "C:~~" and try \
I don't know why that problem happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling says that `￦` character is path separator in Korean windows. `￦` is shown in your screenshot so maybe thats the reason ?

I Wonder what should this show in your python:

```py
import os
print(os.sep)
```

If that shows `￦`, then maybe you could something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
before_file  = Path("C:") / "Users" / "user" / "Desktop" / "before.txt"
before_file.rename("after.txt")
```

Or if you insist on using `os` library, use `os.sep` as path separator instead of `\\` or `/`

Comment: Thank you for writing the answer. Your effort is very helpful me!